# SBT package JAR file for use in lib folder of other projects

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, jar, sbt

How can I create a Jar file which can be placed in the lib folder thus enabling me to import its classes?

I created a jar file from a SBT project, with *sbt package* command.

To see its contents I did *jar -tf myJarFile.jar* for the output:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
fileprocs/
fileprocs/util/
fileprocs/util/PathsAndNames.class
fileprocs/Directory.class
fileprocs/util/PathsAndNames$.class
fileprocs/util/CurriedWorkAction.class
fileprocs/util/CurriedWorkAction$.class
fileprocs/Directory$.class
```

I copied the jar file to the lib folder of another project, in this folder you can see the jar files for Apache Jsvc. These other jar files are expandable and I can import their content like so:

```
import org.apache.commons.daemon.Daemon;
```

[image: 1]

However, my jar file is not expandable and I cannot import it's members, if I try to I get the unresolved symbol error. I had similar results when using *sbt assembly* with the fat jar creating plugin.

Comment: What's your question? Can you clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: @MikeAllen I edited the post and added my question on the top.

Comment: is your _jar_ file the one named `bpfm_2.12-1.0.jar`? If so, I'd agree that it's a little off that _IntelliJ_ isn't allowing you to expand it to look at its contents. Have you tried closing and reopening the project, or refreshing the list of files in `lib`? In the meantime, I'm proposing an alternative solution that might suit you better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not directly address the issue you're reporting, but it's a workaround that you might prefer to your original approach.

Firstly, in the *SBT* project that creates your *jar* file, instead of running `sbt package` and then copying the resulting file manually, you might want to consider publishing it to your local *ivy* repository instead. This is actually very simple to do: just enter the command `sbt publishLocal`. This will both package *and* publish your *jar* file to (I'm guessing, from the contents of your *jar* file, and assuming that your *jar* file is called `bpfm_2.12-1.0.jar`):

`C:\Users\youraccount\.ivy2\local\fileprocs\bpfm_2.12\1.0\jars\bpfm_2.12.jar`

Note: the actual location may differ, but it's not that relevant - it will be within your local *ivy* repository somewhere, and *SBT* will know where to find it. The above assumes that you have the following properties defined in your `bpfm` *jar* file's `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "bpfm"

organization := "fileutils"

version := "1.0"
```

If you also use *SBT* with your *Apache Commons daemon IntelliJ* project above, instead of manually copying this *jar* file to the `lib` directory, you can specify it as a dependency instead. Add the following line to that project's *SBT* `build.sbt` file:

```
libraryDependencies += "fileprocs" %% "bpfm" % "1.0"
```

When *SBT* tries to resolve this dependency, it will find it in the local *ivy* repository. No need to copy anything! *IntelliJ* can be setup to use *SBT* to perform your builds, which means that it will automatically pick-up the *jar* file as a dependency too. What's more, if this *jar* file ever has any dependencies of its own, they'll be captured in the local *ivy* repository too, so you'll never have to worry about copying them over either.

In fact, you can add the *Apache Commons daemon* library as a dependency too. Add the following line to your *SBT* `build.sbt` file:

```
libraryDependencies += "commons-daemon" % "commons-daemon" % "1.0.15"
```

(Indeed, you should only add *jars* to `lib` that are not available via repositories. Go to the [*Maven* central repository](http://mvnrepository.com) to look for artifacts that you can include as dependencies.)

Alternatively, you can add both dependencies with a single property:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "commons-daemon" % "commons-daemon" % "1.0.15",
  "fileprocs" %% "bpfm" % "1.0"
)
```

If you choose to do this, remove the `lib` directory and its contents from your project. (Yet other benefit: referencing libraries as dependencies takes up less space in your `git` repository, and makes merging and branching simpler too.)

**Note**: This will be fine as long as you never plan to publish any of your work to a public repository, since `fileprocs` is not a valid domain name (and so you cannot own it either).

Comment: This approach is not working out of intellij, Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @ManojKumarDhakad Can you elaborate? What isn't working? How have you configured _IntelliJ_ and _SBT_? Could you maybe pose your problem as a separate _Stackoverflow_ question?

Comment: I am able to build in intellijIDEA by adding dependency libraryDependencies += "com.orgname" %% "common-utility" % "0.1" to the new project. But when I am building it in my DEV env by cloning repo from github. It is building fine but when I am running the spark submit. Its throwing some version exception. Would you please suggest which jar like fat or shaded should I create?

Comment: @ManojKumarDhakad I'm sorry, but it's impossible to determine your problem from that description. Can you please post a [_minimal, reproducible example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a separate question, and not as another comment to this answer? Thanks!